# Java Condition.await() is not signaled until its lock calls unlock()

Tags: java, multithreading, async-await, conditional-statements, locking

Java doc for `Condition.await()`:

> The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the
> current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and
> lies dormant until one of four things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the `signal` method for this Condition
>
> ...

I wrote a test program to see, after Thread-1 calls `Condition.await()` and gets blocked, Thread-2 calls `Condition.signal()`.

I expect Thread-1 should return immediately from `await()` and continue.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
public class TestThreadCondition {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Lock rLock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition cond = rLock.newCondition();
        AtomicBoolean aBool = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    rLock.lock();
                    System.out.println("(Step 1) Thread 1 locks and sleeps 1s");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    while (aBool.get()) {
                        System.out.println("(Step 3) Thread 1 enters while loop");
                        cond.await();
                        System.out.println("(Step 5) Thread 1 got signal");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    rLock.unlock();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    System.out.println("(Step 2) Thread 2 also requires lock, blocked");
                    rLock.lock();
                    System.out.println("(Step 4) Thread 2 gets lock after thread 1 cond wait, sends signal");
                    cond.signal(); // I hope this would signal "t1" and t1 will enter (Step 5) immediately.
                    System.out.println("(Step 6) Thread 2 sleeps 3s and set aBool");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    aBool.compareAndSet(true, false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    rLock.unlock();
                    System.out.println("(Step 7) unlock");
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

I **expected** that this program will run and print

```
Step1->Step2->Step3->Step4->Step5->Step6->Step7.
```

But the **actual** result was:

```
(Step 1) Thread 1 locks and sleeps 1s
(Step 2) Thread 2 also requires lock, blocked
(Step 3) Thread 1 enters while loop
(Step 4) Thread 2 gets lock after thread 1 cond wait, sends signal
(Step 6) Thread 2 sleeps 3s and set aBool
(Step 7) unlock
(Step 5) Thread 1 got signal
```

The *Step 5* was executed after *Step6* and *Step7*. It looks like that in Thread-1, `cond.await()` was not awaken when Thread-2 called `cond.signal`, and it blocks until Thread-2 called `rLock.unlock()`.

This seems conflicts with the Javadoc's explanation, as I stated at the beginning. How to understand the behavior of my code?

Answer (score 0):

At the time your code prints

```
(Step 5) Thread 1 got signal
```

Thread1 has already exited the await method. It cannot have gotten that far without already having acquired the lock. So naturally that can't happen if another thread still has the lock.

So your code isn't a good test, we don't know from it whether the signal was delayed until the lock was released, or if the signal occurred earlier than that and thread1 was woken up but was blocking on getting the lock.

In the comparable situation with intrinsic locks it is spelled out in the apidoc that notify is delayed until the notifying thread releases its lock. The waiting thread can't act until then anyway. If that same situation occurs here that would not be surprising.
There isn't a contradiction in the javadoc in any case, waking up and acquiring the lock are two different things.